# The proof of a theorem about an elliptic function.

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

I'm studying The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves by Joseph H.Silverman. In the section VI(Elliptic Curves over $\mathbb{C}$) , the following theorem is;

Let $\mathbb{\Lambda}$ be a lattice.Then
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{\Lambda}) = \mathbb{C}(\wp(z),\wp^\prime (z)),
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{C}(\Lambda)$ is the set of elliptic functions relative to the lattice $\Lambda$ , $\wp (z)$ is the Weierstrass $\wp$-function relative to the lattice $\Lambda$.

I have a quetion about the beginning of the proof.

Proof.

Let $f(z) \in \mathbb{C}(\Lambda)$.Writing
\begin{equation}
f(z) = \dfrac{f(z)+f(-z)}{2} + \dfrac{f(z)-f(-z)}{2},
\end{equation}
we see that it suffices to prove the theorem for functions that are either odd or even.

I don't know why it is sufficient. I'm sorry for the basic question.

Comment: This first summand is an even function, while the second summand is odd.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much.

Comment: Also the theorem follows from the fact entire doubly periodic functions are constant (ie. $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ is a compact Riemann surface) and the usual notation isn't $\mathbb{C}(\Lambda)$